# vba access using PictureEffects

Tags: vba, image, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am looking for using a library in **vba microsoft access 2016** to add some picture effects inside an Image object. All the web examples are for Excel, Word or Powerpoint vba, **not for Access vba**. So I am setting references adding Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library and Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library but code doesn't work with MS Access:

```
'no declare before ...

Dim IMGTEST As Object

IMGTEST = Forms!frmExportOLE.MonImage.Picture  

With IMGTEST.PictureEffects

         ' Insert a 150% Saturation effect.

         .Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 1.5 

         ' Insert Brightness/Contrast effect and set values to -50% Brightness and +25% Contrast.

         Dim brightnessContrast As PictureEffect

         Set brightnessContrast = .Insert(msoEffectBrightnessContrast)

         brightnessContrast.EffectParameters(1).Value = -0.5

         brightnessContrast.EffectParameters(2).Value = 0.25
End With
```

Please, could you tell me what are my mistakes 
and probably help me on what kind dll would i declare before.

Regards michel

Comment: Image manipulation is not available in Access using the default image control. This can't be achieved without either custom ActiveX controls, or using an external program such as ImageMagick to manipulate the images. Asking for off-site resources such as external ActiveX controls that can do this is off-topic here (and as far as I know, most of them are paid).

Comment: Have to use an image editing software to manipulate image for the desired effects then save the edited image for use in Access.